# Save multiple variables from a list of names in one go without using loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, save, cell-array, mat-file

I'm trying to save list of variables from the workspace into a .mat file. The problem I encountered is that I'm trying to make a function of it, and that function should be able to handle a list of variables to be saved. I could loop as below:

```
vars = {'a','b','c'}; % names of variables
for k = 1:numel(vars)
    save(filename,vars(k),'-append');
end
```

but this is not elegant for me and the flag `-append` slowed down the process.
I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
vars = {'a','b','c'}; %names of variables
save(filename,vars);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) expects each variable name as a separate input argument, you can use a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from the cell array:

```
save(filename, vars{:})
```

Comment: Okay I didn't expect it was that easy. Thanks for knocking my head :)